# Asset load from custom folder Leavel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Asset load from custom folder.I have created a folder called 'customasset' inside a public/asset and load a css and js from there.Getting error from a run.Please let me know how to get ride from this.

```
 <script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script> 
    <script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
```

[image: Error images]

Layout file code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<title>App Starter HTML CSS Website Template</title>
<!--
App Starter Template
http://www.templatemo.com/tm-492-app-starter
-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('customasset/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('customasset/css/animate.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('customasset/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('customasset/css/magnific-popup.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('customasset/css/owl.theme.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('customasset/css/owl.carousel.css') }}">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Unica+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Main css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('customasset/css/style.css') }}">
<!-- SCRIPTS -->

<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/magnific-popup-options.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/owl.carousel.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/smoothscroll.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/wow.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/customasset/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-offset="50">


<!-- PRE LOADER -->

<div class="preloader">
     <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
</div>



<!-- Navigation Section -->

@include('inc.navbar')


<!-- Home Section -->

<section id="home" class="main">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

               <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                    <img src="{{ asset('customasset/images/home-img.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Home">
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="home-thumb">
                         <h1 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">App Starter Page</h1>
                         <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">The optimal way to present your beautiful mobile app for your startup team. Let us create amazing things!</p>
                         <a href="#pricing" class="wow fadeInUp section-btn btn btn-success smoothScroll" data-wow-delay="1s">Download App</a>
                    </div>
               </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<!-- About Section -->

<section id="about">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="wow bounceIn section-title">
                         <h1>welcome to new app</h1>
                         <hr>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-6 col-sm-12" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                   <h2>Our Mobile App Team</h2>
                   <h3 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">App Starter page is provided by templatemo that can be used for any site.</h3>
                   <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">This is a responsive <a href="https://plus.google.com/+templatemo" target="_blank">HTML CSS template</a> designed for your mobile app pages. You can modify and use it to fit your needs.</p>
               </div>

               <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-3 col-sm-6" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="about-thumb">
                         <img src="images/team-img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Team">
                              <div class="about-overlay">
                                   <h3>Sandar Lynn</h3>
                                   <h4>UI Designer</h4>
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                    </div>
               </div>

                <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-3 col-sm-6" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="about-thumb">
                         <img src="images/team-img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Team">
                              <div class="about-overlay">
                                   <h3>Candy </h3>
                                   <h4>UX Specialist</h4>
                                   <ul class="social-icon">
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-behance"></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- Divider Section -->

<section id="divider">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <h2 class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">Praesent tempor nec orci eu condimentum. Vestibulum varius lorem sed odio lacinia, ut efficitur tellus convallis. Phasellus convallis est nisi, sit amet accumsan ipsum elementum quis. Mauris ac sem mi.</h2>
                    <a href="#screenshot" class="wow fadeInUp section-btn btn btn-success smoothScroll" data-wow-delay="0.8s">Learn More</a>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- Screenshot Section -->

<section id="screenshot">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="section-title">
                         <h1>App Screenshots</h1>
                         <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">Nulla nisi purus, ultrices et scelerisque at, ullamcorper et ex. Phasellus at nisi lobortis, semper tortor sed, gravida neque.</p>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <!-- Screenshot Owl Carousel -->
               <div id="screenshot-carousel" class="owl-carousel">

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img1.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img2.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img3.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img4.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img5.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img6.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img7.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img7.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/screenshot-img8.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="images/screenshot-img8.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>

               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- Pricing Section -->

<section id="pricing">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="section-title">
                         <h1>App Pricing</h1>
                         <hr>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-4 col-sm-4" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                    <div class="pricing-plan">
                         <div class="pricing-month">
                              <h2>$60</h2>
                         </div>
                         <div class="pricing-title">
                              <h3>Starter</h3>
                         </div>
                         <p>40 Users</p>
                         <p>10GB per user</p>
                         <p>Unlimited Support</p>
                         <p>1 Year License</p>
                         <button class="btn btn-default section-btn">Register now</button>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-4 col-sm-4" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                    <div class="pricing-plan">
                         <div class="pricing-month">
                              <h2>$120</h2>
                         </div>
                         <div class="pricing-title">
                              <h3>Business</h3>
                         </div>
                         <p>100 Users</p>
                         <p>20GB per user</p>
                         <p>Unlimited Support</p>
                         <p>2 Years License</p>
                         <button class="btn btn-default section-btn">Register now</button>
                    </div>
               </div>

               <div class="wow fadeInUp col-md-4 col-sm-4" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                    <div class="pricing-plan">
                         <div class="pricing-month">
                              <h2>$200</h2>
                         </div>
                         <div class="pricing-title">
                              <h3>Advanced</h3>
                         </div>
                         <p>200 Users</p>
                         <p>30GB per user</p>
                         <p>Unlimted Support</p>
                         <p>3 Years License</p>
                         <button class="btn btn-default section-btn">Register now</button>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- Newsletter Section -->

<section id="newsletter">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="wow bounceIn section-title">
                         <h2>Subscribe Newsletter</h2>
                         <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">Maecenas orci sem, mollis quis risus a, venenatis condimentum felis. Integer ut bibendum ipsum. Etiam a tristique sapien, ut dictum augue.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wow fadeInUp newsletter-form" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                         <form action="#" method="post">
                              <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
                                   <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email here">
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5">
                                   <input name="submit" type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit" value="Send Newsletter">
                              </div>
                         </form>
                    </div>
               </div>

          </div>
     </div>
</section>


<!-- Footer Section -->

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

               <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="wow fadeInUp footer-copyright" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                         <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Your App Starter
                         <span>||</span> 
                         Design: <a href="https://plus.google.com/+templatemo" title="free css templates" target="_blank">Templatemo</a></p>
                    </div>
               </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <ul class="wow fadeInUp social-icon" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-dribbble"></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
               </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>


<!-- Modal Contact -->

<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content modal-popup">
          <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <h2 class="modal-title">Contact Form</h2>
          </div>

               <form action="#" method="post">
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="3" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit" value="Send Message">
               </form>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>


<!-- Back top -->

<a href="#" class="go-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its crystal clear, you have syntax error, recheck your code or add your code with question if you want others to help

Comment: I have updated but still have an issue

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '')); ?>"></script> ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' (View:

Comment: your code and what is shown in screenshot seems different, please check what is your actual code first

Comment: yes I have just updated and paste updated code

Comment: please show the code where error is occurring, find the code that showing in your screenshots and share or share the full blade file

Comment: Sohel error is fixed but I have one query when I put js in footer will give me an error for the same code.If apply same code in header will work perfectly.

Comment: then there is a syntax error in your code between header and footer which resulting error, this might be some issue with quotation using on html tag

Comment: I have added a code for layout file will please examine and put in answer.

Comment: see my answer, find that line and replace it, you are making syntax error when adding home img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
<img src="{{ asset('customasset/images/home-img.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Home">
```

To

```
<img src="{{ asset('customasset/images/home-img.png') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="Home">
```

Comment: get it if there is any error layout will be appear break.

Comment: yes, sometimes a modern ide can help you to identify this kind of mistakes

Comment: using sublime but can't getting any kind of thing.Is there anyother free version editor?

Comment: i think sublime has a lot of free plugins for formatting, may be you can look for one and add it

Comment: ok Is it something you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606407/create-a-vhost-in-ubantu-16-04

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
<script src="{{ asset('public/assets/customasset/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I think public will repeat if doing same

Comment: You can try it.

Comment: I have to build layout and I have copy all things in public/customasset/JS and css and images. Created one layouts folder and added app.blade.php

Comment: <script src="{{ public_path('customasset/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>

Comment: This is not standard way to include.