# Create a Vhost in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, lampp

I have started working in laravel and using lampp. I have watched many tutorials that use a vhost to make user-friendly url. I want to do it on Ubuntu 16.04.

> Following tutorial is not working for me:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/302/how-to-setup-a-virtual-host-locally-with-xampp-in-ubuntu

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/basicwebsite/public"
    ServerName mywebsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Setup a virtual host for a Laravel project**

1. First, copy the default configuration file and rename it:

> $sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/myVhost

2. open myVhost.conf file using this command:

> $sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/myVhost.conf

3. Add the directives:

**assuming that the Laravel project is in /var/www/html/**

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
serverName www.myAwesomeLink.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel-app/public


<Directory /var/www/html/laravel-app>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

so now the file will look something like this:

[image: myVhost.conf file]

save and close.

4. Now add an entry in the hosts file:

> $sudo nano /etc/hosts

add this line:

```
127.0.0.1   www.myAwesomeLink.com
```

save and close.

5. Enable site and the rewrite mode:

> $sudo a2enmod rewrite
>
> $sudo a2ensite myVhost.conf

6. Restart the server:

> $sudo service apache2 restart

7. Serve the Laravel project:

open the project folder

> php artisan serve

**this will serve on port 8000 by default**

you can also specify the port

> php artisan serve --port=4200

8. Open the browser:

> http://www.myAwesomeLink.com:8000

or any other specified port.

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://docs.serverpress.com/article/232-how-to-change-top-level-domain-dev-extension-google-chrome-users).

Its not working because the browsers have updated their security terms and policies including SSL certificates over `.dev` domains. just change your extension from `.dev` to something else like `.localhost` or `.test`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/basicwebsite/public"
ServerName dev.mywebsite.test
</VirtualHost>
```

Also change the extension in `/etc/hosts` from `.dev` to `.test`.

```
127.0.0.1  dev.mywebsite.test
```

Also keep in mind to restart the service to load the new added virtual host i.e: restart the Apache server

Hope it helps.

Comment: This site can’t be reached
mywebsite.test’s server IP address could not be found.

Comment: Also edit the extension in custom domain in the hosts file of your system. that is the step no:2 in the tutorial you stated in the question.

Comment: I can't find host file

Comment: http://dev.mywebsite.test/  You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

Comment: grant all the permission to the project folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168031/discussion-between-parthu-panther-and-vasim-vanzara).

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to add a host in `/etc/hosts`. Open the hosts file and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1 mywebsite.dev
```

You will need to restart server after this.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create new file under this path /etc/apache2/sites-available/myweb.conf

2.Copy the following to the file

```
  # Indexes + Directory Root.
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite/public
  ServerName dev.mywebsite.test
  <Directory "/var/www/html/mywebsite/public">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  Allow from all

  </Directory>
```

3.Run "sudo a2ensite myweb.conf"

4.Add this line "Listen 80" to file "/etc/apache2/ports.conf"

5.Restart apache server

Comment: Looking for Ubuntu